# Usage of participles indicating the object

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, participles

> You left them alone, ***crying*** for their mama. (Context: Children
> were crying not "you")

Is this sentence grammatically correct? I have seen a television character use a sentence similiar to this one above.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is correct, the main part being:

> crying for their mama